# Need 1 customer per row with the total of that customer's combined orders to display in last column

Tags: sql, join

**Tables and prompt**

[image]

Newer to SQL and taking a college course. I was able to join my 3 tables but can't figure out how to get all my customer orders to display right. I need to show total dollar amount of all purchases by each customer. Currently showing all orders by each customer.

```
SELECT Customers.Customer#, Customers.lastname, Customers.firstname, MAX(Orders.Orderdate) "Last Order On", Orderitems.Paideach "Total Purchased in $"
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customer# = Orders.Customer#
RIGHT JOIN Orderitems ON Orders.Order# = Orderitems.Order#
GROUP BY Customers.Customer#, Customers.lastname, Customers.firstname, Orders.Orderdate, Orderitems.Paideach
ORDER BY Customer#;
```

Comment: Play around with the `GROUP BY`. You are creating additional 'grains' with use of columns like `Orderdate`. Sounds like you would want to group on a single column, ideally a unique customer ID. Take a look at 'ROLL UP' keyword. Might help in experimenting.

Comment: What do the tables look like? Likely you are grouping by too much. Then you probably want to use the `SUM` function in your `SELECT` for each of the grouped sets of rows to get the total by customer.

Comment: @dpwrussell Thanks for taking a look. I just added a picture of the tables. I originally started off with limiting my group by statement only listing one column but receiving "not a GRUP BY function". Thought I was getting this stuff and now just feel lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM function to display the total amount of purchases made by the customer. Update your query to:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer#, Customers.lastname, Customers.firstname, MAX(Orders.Orderdate) "Last Order On", SUM(Orderitems.Paideach) "Total Purchased in $"
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customer# = Orders.Customer#
INNER JOIN Orderitems ON Orders.Order# = Orderitems.Order#
GROUP BY Customers.Customer# 
ORDER BY Customer#;
```

Comment: HI Sandeep, appreciate the help on this. I actually had recently edited my query to have the SUM function in my SELECT statement and tried to cut down on my GROUP BY function. I'm continuously getting a "not a GROUP BY expression" error.

Comment: @Nick You're getting the error because of the default sql mode value. Following are the steps to get rid of the error message you're getting:

log into phpMyAdmin -> Under  Server:LocalDatabae -> Edit sql mode value to blank. By default it is "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

After editing the sql mode value to blank, run the query. Ideally, it should get rid off the error you're getting.

Comment: It seems highly likely that this is wrong (through no fault of @Sandeep) because I would guess ( but can't be sure of the business semantics) that total paid would be `Quantity * PaidEach`.

Comment: @dpwrussell You're correct. SUM(Quantity * PaidEach) would give the total amount of the purchases made by the customer. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Nick Update: You're getting the error because of the default sql mode value. Following are the steps to get rid of the error message you're getting: log into phpMyAdmin -> Under Server:LocalDatabae -> variables -> Edit sql mode value to blank. 

By default it is: "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" .

After editing the sql mode value to blank, run the query. Ideally, it should get rid off the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you also need to multiply quantity by the price of each unit.

```
SELECT Customers.Customer#,
       Customers.lastname,
       Customers.firstname,
       MAX(Orders.Orderdate) "Last Order On",
       SUM(Orderitems.Paideach * Orderitems.Quantity) "Total Purchased in $"
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customer# = Orders.Customer#
INNER JOIN Orderitems ON Orders.Order# = Orderitems.Order#
GROUP BY Customers.Customer# 
ORDER BY Customer#;
```